# How to setup serve static assets with an efficient cache policy for third party with apache?

Tags: google-pagespeed

In Magento 2, I have checked my site speed in Google page speed tool. In my site, there are YouTube videos render on page. So, This error I can't solve in google page speed tool.

[image]

This all images and js you can see in above screenshot that all files render from youtube.

How can i solve this error and increase my site speed?

Comment: Ive found a good article here 
https://amasty.com/blog/magento-store-leverage-browser-caching